# Google Script: service not found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, service

Please Help:

I used a script to capture URL's. It runs perfectly on another sheet (with modifications of- course). However when i run it (code below) it give me an error "Service not found: url shortener v1Dismiss"

The thing is that the function i am using is called 'GetEditResponseURL' but the error indicates "url shortener v1"

Comment: Please post the code you are using.

Comment: Resources> Advanced Google services> Enable Url Shortener